# Why driver_execute has a empty value

Tags: javascript, python-3.x, selenium, firefox, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to send text into textfield.

```
binary = FirefoxBinary("C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\Firefox.exe")

driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_binary=binary)

text = 'sending something to the text area'

input_field = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('.trumbowyg-editor')

input_field.clear()

driver.execute_script("arguments[0].value = arguments[1];", input_field, 'sending something to the text area')
```

But it doesn't work, doesn't do anything and there are no any errors.

Also, I tried in following way:

```
binary = FirefoxBinary("C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\Firefox.exe")

driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_binary=binary)

text = 'sending something to the text area'

input_field = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('.trumbowyg-editor')

input_field.clear()

driver.send_keys(text)
```

And it works. But, I want to send text with javascript code, because of it more faster than `driver.send_keys()` command.

Answer (score 0):

If python binding to selenium works similar to java binding, then that script executor expects is a string, containing javascirpt that could be executed in browser console to achieve the desired result.

In this case passing input_field (which is probably some python object) to the script executor will not do the trick. What you want to pass to it is:

```
driver.execute_script('document.getElementsByClassName("trumbowyg-editor")[0].se‌​tAttribute("value", arguments[0]);','sending something to the text area')
```

meaning that searching for the element has to be done within the script as well.

Comment: it's not working for me. I got error that arguments[1] is not defined.

Comment: So, I have find another workaround in following way:

driver.execute_script("arguments[0].innerHTML = arguments[1];", input_field, 'sending something to the text area')

But in this way, there is strange issue, replaced value has not been saved.

Comment: ok. my bad (I am not from python world). Ofc it should be arguments[0], since I've removed one argument from  the function call. Also, I had a typo    class name has to be without the '.' prefix. The key here is first to try out the line in browser console. Only when it works in there its a good idea to run it with the script executor.

Comment: I see... But the problem is that it's not saved again, moreover, when I used
`driver.execute_script('document.getElementsByClassName("trumbowyg-editor")[0].value=arguments[0];','sending something to the text area')`
it's not write in textfield, when I changed to
`driver.execute_script('document.getElementsByClassName("trumbowyg-editor")[0].innerHTML=arguments[0];','sending something to the text area')` then it was written.

Comment: That is because script, which you execute, is not doing what you want it to do. As I have written in the answer, if it works in the developers tools in console, then it should work with script executor. It should be: 'document.getElementsByClassName("trum‌​bowyg-editor")[0].setAttribute("value", arguments[0]‌);' Edited the answer as well.

Comment: ok, but your suggested way not working, it's not writing in it.